# C++ strtok return error

Tags: c++

```
string result="CCY 1.2597 Down 0.0021(0.16%) 14:32 SGT [44]";
char* token;
char* buffer[result.length() + 1];  //Space for '\0'

strcpy(buffer, result.c_str());
buffer[result.length()] = '\0';     //insert '\0'
token = strtok(buffer, " ");
while (token != NULL) {
  /* work with token */
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

I not sure why the above code got error, what is wrong with my code

```
main.cpp:51:30: error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
main.cpp:53:27: error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strtok(char*, const char*)’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 893ms)
```

Comment: Why use `std::string` at all: `char buffer[] = "CCY 1.2597 Down 0.0021(0.16%) 14:32 SGT [44]";`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems with your code: Firstly, the variable type for `buffer` is wrong, which is the error the compiler finds. Secondly, you are (probably unknowingly) deviating from the C++ standard by using the non-standard variable length array (VLA) extension of the gcc. This feature is standard in C from C99 on, but not in C++.

For the variable declaration, the following line is wrong:

```
char* buffer[result.length() + 1];
```

This line allocates an array of pointers to characters on the stack. However, `strcpy` expects a single pointer to a character vector.  While an array type (like `char[]`) decays into a pointer (`char*`), an array of pointers to characters (`char*[]`) decays into `char**`, which is one pointer too many. Declare instead:

```
char buffer[result.length() + 1];
```

Now, this will still compile **only on gcc**. To make your code compatible, you'll have to make the memory
allocation dynamic, e.g. by using:

```
char *buffer = new char[result.length() + 1];
```

and then performing

```
delete[] buffer;
```

at the end of your routine. You should use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) to make your life easier here.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition

```
char* buffer[result.length() + 1];
```

is wrong.

```
char* buffer = new char[result.length() + 1];
```

You have to initialize the c-string with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Is there a reason to use heap instead of stack allocation? I suspect the different allocation will confuse the OP and divert from the real type issue.

Comment: @thiton Does C++ even support VLAs? I thought that was a C99 thing.

Comment: @thiton : How the compiler know how many bytes to be reserved in stack at compile time?

Comment: Yes, VLAs are nonstandard in C++ and a gcc extension => dynamic allocation is preferable here. Could you explain that in your answer, or may I update it accordingly? The issue is real, but needs elaboration.

Comment: @thiton : I'm surprised that it such an extension is available. How does the compiler knows about the size?

Comment: @PermanentGuest: It doesn't, and it needn't. At runtime, the stack top pointer is simply modified as needed for the dynamic array size.

Comment: ok, interesting... new learning for the day... anyway, my msvc2010 compiler doesn't allow that..

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point here. I've modified my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

The `buffer` should not be `char*`, but just `char`.

It will *contain* the characters, not point to them.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration off `buffer` is wrong. Get rid of the '*'.
It should be

```
char buffer[result.length() + 1];
```